# pcre.trackback limit php preg_replace_callback()

Tags: php, regex

I'm using preg_replace_callback to append parameters to specific URLs in outgoing emails.

The process works by loading up an email template from a database, pulling a list of users from the same database, and then passing the email body through this function:

```
function add_user_login($body, $user_id, $user_hash) {
  ini_set('pcre.backtrack_limit',1000000000);
  $return_string = preg_replace_callback('@(https?://([-\w\.]+)+mydomain.com([^"]*))@', function ($matches) use ($user_id, $user_hash) {

      if (strpos($matches[0], "?") === false) {
        return $matches[0] . "?user_id=" . $user_id . "&user_hash=" . $user_hash;
      } else {
        return $matches[0] . "&user_id=" . $user_id . "&user_hash=" . $user_hash;
      }
    }, $body);

  return $return_string;
}
```

The goal is that anything with "www.mydomain.com" or "mydomain.com" will get the GET parameters "user_id" and "user_hash" appended to them.  Unfortunately, there may or may not already be existing GET parameters and other things going on with these non-uniform URLs so this has been the best method I've found so far to do this.

My problem is that for some reason I was getting backtrack_limit errors in testing and had to increase my backtrack_limit.  This worked in testing but it's incredibly slow.

Has anyone else done something similar?  I've tried modifying my regex and I think the backtrack issue comes from my wildcard usage, but any modifications I've made caused it to not work.

Comment: Just replace `([-\w\.]+)+` with `[-\w.]+` and retry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex you have contains a nested quantifier inside  - `([-\w\.]+)+`. This subpattern when enclosed with subpatterns that can match the same characters causes huge amount of backtracking steps.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xY4cO1/1): 26,664 steps to complete the match. With `https://see.my-cool-site.here.mydomain.c` (a non-matching string) we get a catastrophical backtracking issue.

The solution is to just use `[-\w.]+`:

```
'@(https?://[-\w\.]+mydomain.com([^"]*))@'
```

You may keep a capturing group over the pattern if you need the value before `mydomain.com` (however, judging by your code, you only need the whole match):

```
'@(https?://([-\w\.]+)mydomain.com([^"]*))@'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xY4cO1/2)

Comment: Why would anyone downvote this answer?  It explains the problem and provides a solution.

Comment: Yeah, that's odd.  It wasn't me btw.  I upvoted and accepted the answer.  I wonder if someone accidentally downvoted it.  Thanks for your answer, it was very helpful.